# Additional query in the Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to make a variable that stores a Boolean value. is_following field indicates whether the current user is signed (under which the authorization is made). I would like a solution that would be nice and fast. My models are as follows:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int FollowerCount { get; set; } = 0;
    public int FollowingCount { get; set; } = 0;

    //I would like here to store a value to the status of subscription. This column must not be in the database.
    public bool IsFollowing { get; set; } = false; 

    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [Required]
    protected virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

FOLLOWING TABLE (MODEL):

```
public class Following
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FollowerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser FollowerUser { get; set; }
}
```

The first thing that comes to mind is to make an additional request for every request:

```
var following = db.Followings.Any(u => u.FollowerId == uId && u.UserId == currentUserId);
```

I is not suitable, because the whole project where the user sample, I have to do this additional request.

UPDATE:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual bool Is_Following { get
{
   var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

   using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
   {
        var userid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == currentUser);
        if(userid!=null)
          return db.Followings.Any(u => u.FollowerId == UserId && u.UserId == UserId);
   }
   return false;
}
```

At least how you can use the current context without creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works, but not a perfect solution:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual bool Is_Following { get
        {
            var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            if (currentUser == null) return false;

            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var userid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == currentUser).Id;
                if(userid!=null)
                    return db.Followings.Any(u => u.FollowerId == userid && u.UserId == UserId);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about Repository pattern? https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

It helps you nice and easy implement what do you need.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have and implement. But it is not suitable for my task, I would like to retrieve data from the table "following" was held together with the user obtain (table "UserInfo"). The update to the top of my record, I added that I wanted.